# Why did Diana's mom lead a war for freedom?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

Why did Diana's mom say she lead a war for freedom in *Wonder Woman*? Freedom from what exactly? I thought the Amazons were created to live with man? When were they ever enslaved?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought the Amazons were created to live with man? When were they ever enslaved?

## During the war with Ares

Ares refused to give up his hold on mankind and created an army to battle the gods and the Amazons and at **this** point we see them enslaved.

[image]

The [**script**](https://ricgibbs.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Wonder-Woman_Allan-Heinberg_2017.pdf)..

> ```
>                       ANTIOPE (V.O.)
>            Ares refused to give up his hold
>           on mankind. Tightening his grip,
>           he turned them against us.
>
>          ARES AND HIS ARMY OF MEN lead Hippolyta and the other
>          Amazons out of a BURNING CITY in SHACKLES and CHAINS.
>
>
>          When Zeus led the gods to our
>          defense, Ares killed them, one-by-one....... until only Zeus himself              
>          remained.
>
>               HIPPOLYTA breaks the chains between her bracelets!
>
>                           ANTIOPE (V.O.)
>           Your mother, the Amazon Queen, led
>           a revolt that freed us all from
>           enslavement.
> ```

Comment: would you please explain the script or share some link in which it describes clearly.

Comment: It's pretty clear from what I said. They were enslaved during the war with Ares. I don't see how I can make it any clearer